# Multiple Concurrent Calls FastAPI in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, gunicorn, fastapi

I'm hosting FastApi with Gunicorn on a EC2 AWS instance.
I have added `worker-connection` parameter and set it to 100 but based on my test I don't feel that the client requests are handled concurrently. For example if I send 3 request at the same time one of them always gets processed after the other two. I'm attaching the command to start the application. Am I missing something?

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "app.test:app", "--worker-tmp-dir" , "/dev/shm/" , "-w", "3", "--threads", "12", "--timeout","120", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:80", "-k","uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--worker-connections", "100" , "--log-level",  "debug" , "--preload"]
```

Answer (score 0):

With your configuration your are setup to use 3 async workers so the problem is not here. since you are creating your instance without conf file it's probably not a problem with you server/service not taking the conf.

So what could be wrong ?

are you sure that EC2 aws is suitable for paralelized process ?

you can follow [this guide](https://medium.com/building-the-system/gunicorn-3-means-of-concurrency-efbb547674b7) to setup a good gunicorn implementation.

**1st means of concurrency (workers, aka UNIX processes)**

Each of the workers is a UNIX process that loads the Python application. There is no shared memory between the workers.

The suggested number of workers is (2*CPU)+1.

For a dual-core (2 CPU) machine, 5 is the suggested workers value.

You can also follw [this guide](https://medium.com/@nhudinhtuan/gunicorn-worker-types-practice-advice-for-better-performance-7a299bb8f929) to know wich worker type use for every usecase. in your case since you are using fastapi "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker" should be just fine.

Comment: Thanks @BastienB, I already went through those guides and applied them. However, this doesn't seem to solve the problem. Could you suggest me a more effective way to test the concurrent requests?